# PerformancePoint, SharePoint 2010 and JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

Are there any events that PerformancePoint Dashboards emit after loading data that can be leveraged by JQuery.  The document.ready fires before the performancepoint dashboard has rendered so that doesn't help.  I need for the performancepoint dashboard to render so I can then use JQuery to manipulate the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

A co-worker of mine, Chris E., dug into the assemblies and found that we could create a function called NotifyBrowserOfAsyncUpdate and that PerformancePoint would call it after loading.

function NotifyBrowserOfAsyncUpdate (elem) {

//execute jquery in here

}

Comment: This could be very helpful.  Thanks for the research!